# Offline Geographical Maps in Web Application after converting .osm to .map

Tags: web-applications, maps, offline, openstreetmap, gis

I have this very basic requirement for providing offline maps in my web application.
My web-application cannot access internet and hence all online API's for showing map is ruled out completely.

After doing research,I downloaded the .osm.pbf format file for the desired location(Say a particular city). 
I

> converted .osm.pbf to .osm file

Next step I generated tiles using this .osm file.

> The tiles are stored on my local directory.
>
> My final Step is to show these tiles as a map in web-browser inside my
>   application (Java EE) and place a marker given the latitude and longitude
>   of a place.

This is the only requirement I have to show inside the offline map.

I have the tile for a particular city.But I don't know how to use it and show offline map..

> By the term offline I mean, the application is hosted on Intranet on
>   application server and under no circumstances internet access is
>   provided.

Kindly guide.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms Are there no offline tiles providers? I am struggling with a similar TODO that I am trying out for my learning. I am using the leaflet library but am not getting a good offline tile dataset which I can point to render the map.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a mapping library that could be downloaded and reside inside your application. There are several but the most common ones are [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). Both support custom tile layers.

For example, assuming that your tiles are inside the web-application at a folder called "tiles", a possible layer definition would be (in Leaflet):

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

or even in other machine in the intranet

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://intranetmachine/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

Comment: Leaflet can be used only to invoke or use the existing tiles. How do I create tiles of the desired location?

Comment: Created tiles. Wrote the mentioned code inside a demo javascript function. The function is called when I click on button. But nothing is displayed on page apart from Powered by leaflet and two small images + and -. How do i display the map?

Comment: Could be lots of things. First, I'm assuming you don't have the tiles for the whole planet, so the initial zoom in the map should match your tiles. Also, use something like Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see the tiles that the map control is trying to fetch. Should be helpful7

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

Save the leaflet .js and .css files locally.

- http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.css
- http://leafletjs.com/dist/leaflet.js

See the source code of this basic example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html

Change  the .css, .js paths to your local copies, and the tileLayer path to local as described.

See the code for the marker:

```
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

I'm guessing that's what you need. Remove the other polygons and the click-show-lat-long function if necessary.

If you want the map to be full-screen, change the `<div..` tag to 100%.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Do you have any clue on some of the good offline tiles providers? I am scouting for one. Had a look at unfolding maps but that was  not of much help. Mapbox at /www.mapbox.com/ doesn't have any help to a web based app. Still reading OpenLayers to see if it provides a set of tiles to work in offline mode.