# Building an offline web application using openlayers

Tags: geospatial, openlayers, openstreetmap, qgis

I am trying to build an **offline** web application using **openlayers** as shown in the sample code below. However the map does not load with the error (as shown in the firebug):

```
Error: "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/4/6/6.png"
```

I read through other Q/As on this and found that I need to download some of the map layers (image/tile/vector) and refer it locally. But I guess there are other sub steps to it. Anyone who has already tried doing this and know exactly the steps to be done for it? 
I came across this question in SO [Offline Geographical Maps in Web Application after converting .osm to .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704632/offline-geographical-maps-in-web-application-after-converting-osm-to-map) but it doen't have a detailed answer to how to set the offline map repository.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myOfflineWebAppWebContent/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="myOfflineWebAppWebContent/js/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Hello Open Layers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Javascript` is not `Java`!

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that's pretty informative! :) Thanks! Had added it to have a greater reach to this offline map problem but yes it would confuse the reader more than reaching out to them. Removed the  tag. Thanks!

Comment: I do not know how you could use an **online** map **offline**....

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Hi Usagi, I am reading on that. there is a way out of storing the tiles of the map as an offline repo and then reading them locally. Openstreetmap and qgis have some steps to it. But i am struggling to pick up those steps in order. Will keep u posted as i get closer to the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704632/offline-geographical-maps-in-web-application-after-converting-osm-to-map